# Elastic-search aggregate top 3 common result

Tags: elasticsearch

My indexed data is of below structure, i want to aggregate top 3 most repeted productProperty, so top 3 most repeated productProperty will be there in aggregation result

```
  [
    {
        productProperty: "material",
        productValue:[{value: wood},{value: plastic}] ,
    },
    {
        productProperty: "material",
        productValuea:[{value: wood},{value: plastic}] ,
    },
    {
        productProperty: "type",
        productValue:[{value: 26A},{value: 23A}] ,
    },
    {
        productProperty: "type",
        productValue:[{value: 22B},{value: 90C}] ,
    },
    {
        productProperty: "material",
        productValue:[{value: wood},{value: plastic}] ,
    },
    {
        productProperty: "age_rating",
        productValue:[{value: 18},{value: 13}] ,
    }
    ]
```

Below query aggregates all based on productProperty but how can i get top 3 results out of that

```
{
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_product_property": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": []
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "aggs": {
          "productProperty": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "productProperty"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) parameter in your `term aggregation`.

```
{
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_product_property": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": []
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "aggs": {
          "productProperty": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "productProperty", 
             "size" : 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Important to point out, that terms aggregations are not the *most* accurate in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Tushar you can use the [`size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) param. According to the [ES official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

> when there are lots of unique terms, Elasticsearch only returns the
> top terms; this number is the sum of the document counts for all
> buckets that are not part of the response

However, you can define the order in which the sorting of the results should be done of the aggregation response, using the `order` param.
By default, the result is sorted on the basis of doc count in descending order

Search Query will be

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "productProperty": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "productProperty.keyword",
        "size": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And, search result would be

```
"aggregations": {
    "productProperty": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "material",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "type",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "age_rating",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```